# How do I insert symbols in "Games for Windows Live" messages?

Tags: games-for-windows-live

I want to add the insert coin symbol (see picture) to my messages in SSFIVAE for PC. The image shows the text message screen on Xbox, which is not available on PC.

How can input the insert coin symbol?

I know I can add special characters with Alt + number (e.g. Alt+0128 is €). More codes are on http://www.alt-codes.net/ ,  but there is no insert coin symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Microsoft Points symbol is really just the [generic currency character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_%28typography%29#Other_usages) (¤). When this symbol's character code appears in text on the XBox, the Dashboard renders it as the Microsoft Points symbol instead. Consequently, there's no trivial way to use the actual symbol on any other platform.

You could use a font that rendered ¤ as the MS Points symbol instead, but both you and the recipient of the message would have to be using the same font. Windows Live uses such a font and you can paste `¤` into the text window or type <kbd>ALT</kbd> + 0164 using the numeric keypad (see image).

[image: Currency symbol input]

Research sources: [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_%28typography%29#Other_usages)], [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBUqM.png)]

Comment: Props to you for finding this information. I modified your answer, as it needed only some tweaking.

Comment: @ayckoster It uses the same font! Well isn't that convenient. Sometimes, things just work out. :)

Answer (score 5):

That's actually not an "insert coin" symbol, but rather [the symbol for Microsoft Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Points) (the currency used on various Microsoft services, including Xbox Live).

The reason you can't add that character to messages is, as you might guess, because typical PC fonts don't contain a glyph for that. This is also the reason why you don't see it on ASCII character maps.

Comment: Is this definitely not possible? I mean there are many custom fonts, like Windings that might include this symbol. MS could use a custom font for Games for Windows Live.

Comment: its not really about fonts. its a character mapping.
even MS isnt dumb enough to try and tack on a new unicode character just for one of there icons. and its not a sane idea for any font to replace a currently in use (and standardised) character just for that symbol.

Comment: @TrewTzu Well it *could* be just about fonts. After all, the private-use area of Unicode is intended to solve exactly the problem you mention. As it turns out though, they did just replace a standard symbol—ironically, one that was never meant to *have* a standard rendering in Unicode since it was designed to be replaced first!

Comment: heh! id never heard of the generic currency character. thats quite cool. thanks.